# Google Street View - Sorry we don't have that address

Tags: xcode, google-maps, google-street-view

When working with `google street view` some times there is a missing image for a specific coordinate and it returns either an image with a `sorry` message or an image of map with x (not the nicest one) the `JSon` returning from the street view is only the image - no status or other information.

In case there is no image I wish to display my own image - how can I know the returning image is the sorry message?